# Python XML DOM unique object?

Tags: python, xml, dom, reference

I have a problem understanding pythons way of handling references in lists. I tried googling and reading python books but did not find a suitable answer for my problem.

If I have a file called test.py with the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
__check = ET.Entity('check')

def test():
    entries = []
    for c in range(2):
        row = []

        row.append(ET.Element('entry'))
        a = ET.Element('entry')
        a.append(__check)
        row.append(a)
        entries.append(row)

    for row in entries:
        for e in row:
           ET.dump(e)
```

When executing the test() method the output is:

```
<entry/>
<entry/>
<entry/>
<entry>&check;</entry>
```

The expected output would be:

```
<entry/>
<entry>&check;</entry>
<entry/>
<entry>&check;</entry>
```

What am I missing? For sure I can just edit the line with `a.append(__check)` to `a.append(copy.deepcopy(__check))` and it works. But I don't understand why the previous example does not work the way I think.

Edit: I am using python 2.7.6

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is surprising you, but I suggest you read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Well as it seems you are not suprised by the ouput. If so I would be glad if you could explain to me, why it is like it is. If you are trying to say that this is a python thing you should be able to explain it. But the answer below states that this is not a python thing instead it is an XML specific thing, because the same element is not allowed to be in the tree multiple times.

Comment: *"I tried googling and reading python books but did not find a suitable answer"* - how am I supposed to know what you've seen so far, what you understood (or not) and dismissed as not a possibility? This is why I didn't try to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link anyway, I think I already understood most, if not all, of the concept from that link. It seems that I just missed the fact that each element in an XML DOM has to have a unique object reference?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending the same element over and over. XML DOM does not allow the same element to exist in two places in the tree (it wouldn't be a tree if it did), so your second append moves the `__check` element to the new place in the tree.

Comment: So it is not a python specific thing, instead it is specific to the XML DOM tree?

Comment: @user3768317 Well, it's both in the sense that you need to understand python's behaviour, and how an XML DOM is expected to behave.

Comment: I understand that I am referencing the same Object over and over again as I am not new to programming, but I didn't know that each element in an XML DOM has to be unique in the sense of an object.